# How do I extend Kotlin string-interpolation to work with a custom class?

Tags: android, kotlin, string-interpolation

From what I have read in the documentation, it is my understanding that string interpolation in Kotlin works such that this code:

`val n = 5
    println("N is $n")`

translates to

`StringBuilder().append("N is ").append(n).toString()`

which is fine and dandy for types for which Stringbuilder.append() has an implementation. I want now to use the Kotlin extension mechanic to be able to append my own class:

`class Foo(a: Int = 0, b: Float = 0f) {}
    fun Stringbuilder.append(aFoo: Foo) : Stringbuilder! {
        return this.append("A = $a, B = $b")
    }`

so that when I call:

`aFoo = Foo(3,5.0f)
    println("aFoo parameters are: $aFoo")`

it prints: "aFoo parameters are: A = 3, B = 5.0"

Unfortunately, it seems that my extension is shadowed by:

`public open fun append(obj: Any!): StringBuilder!`

I didn't manage to find in the documentation a way around this... Suggestions?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could achieve that by overriding toString of Foo.

```
class Foo(val a: Int = 0, val b: Float = 0f) {

    override fun toString(): String {
        return "A = $a, B = $b"
    }

}
```